# send mail later in Gnus

Tags: gnus, email

I'm trying to find out if there is way to schedule a mail for later delivery in Gnus. I am not trying to just queue a mail to be sent whenever a connection becomes available, but I am looking for a feature to define a date at which a mail is to be sent.

Comment: Here is a [way](http://teaching.sociology.ul.ie/bhalpin/wordpress/?p=236) of achieving what you want. You'll let us know if working.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

There is, you need to:

```
; Activate delayed messages:
(gnus-delay-initialize)
```

And this is also handy:

```
; Remove date, so delayed messages (C-c C-j) don't get a date until
; sent <mailman.1180.1266014215.14305.info-gnus-english@gnu.org>:
(setq message-draft-headers '(References From))
```

automated sending is activated by this (otherwise it will be sent the first time you fetch new email after time is up, I think):

```
; Demon to send queued email every other minute:
(gnus-demon-add-handler 'gnus-delay-send-queue 1 nil)
(gnus-demon-init)
```

To use it, write your email, and instead of pressing `C-c C-c` to send it, you press `C-c C-j` and are prompted for when you want the email sent (time, date, or delay).

The email will show up in a special group called `nndraft:delayed` where you can delete or edit it if you change your mind.